# Should we start directing people to the Health SE for general nutrition/health questions?

Tags: discussion

We've had a number of questions regarding general unrelated to exercise. I just recently learned that there's a [Health SE in Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health?referrer=3bnJk5Umd0S9V8Fef65Ucg2). Should we start direction people over there when we vote to close off-topic questions?

It's only just now in private beta, but maybe it's something for us to keep an eye on and/or for people with experience to start cross-promoting with. My chief worry is avoiding the "you really should see your doctor" situation we often have to use on this site.

Comment: I was going to +1 this anyway, then realised it was you that answered my (now deleted) question with regards to general nutrition yesterday. I actually looked for a 'Health & Fitness' SE before I ended up here and was surprised that it didn't exist. Having said that, still not sure if my question would have fit any better in the Health SE, *but* it's a good one to have anyway.

Comment: I know the scope got narrowed here to dump nutrition, but there's *a lot* of middle ground between "fitness" and "health".

Comment: {nods} Arguably, there's room for a Nutrition site. Incidentally, on the Health SE, there's a brief discussion of how Cooking similarly had to boot "nutrition" from its scope.

Comment: I've been on the health site for a bit, and it's so wide ranging I think they're going to have big problems with scope and accuracy. Everything from "how much sugar can I have" to "my back hurts" to "preparing myself mentally for surgery" will be in scope.

Comment: Yeah. *sigh* Unfortunately, the internet is a pretty bad place to ask for medical advice, but people still keep doing it, particularly since, even with insurance, you're looking at losing $20-40 just to ask a question.

Comment: @EricKaufman - Same here. Although, scope can be narrowed, as was seen when nutrition not related to exercise was declared OT here. I think it will get tightened up when in public beta, there are already some good discussions on scope, needing sources, etc. I do think it's a good place to send people for general nutrition questions if/once it makes it to public beta.

Comment: Especially since the nutrition proposal seems stalled.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if we could say "try Ask Metafilter" or something at least, but you have to pay for that. Are there any good symptom forums on the Web?

Answer (score 0):

https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/88/how-should-ovo-lacto-vegetarians-compensate-the-lack-of-meat-in-their-diets

That is one of 33 questions currently marked with the nutrition tag, so at least at to start, it appears that many of the nutrition sans workout info questions that we receive can be redirected to the Health beta.

It went public today, so we should be able to flag for migration.

https://health.stackexchange.com/